# How to add crossdomain.xml in sub directory

Tags: javascript, adobe, cross-domain, html5boilerplate, cross-domain-policy

The [spec for cross domain policy files](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html) says that you can put a the `crossdomain.xml` file outside the root through the use of a `X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies` header. How exactly does one go about doing that? I want to put a `crossdomain.xml` file in a sub directory (I don't have access to the root). This is from page 11 of [the spec](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html):

> When clients require a policy file, they look at the root by default. A
>   domain should always host a master policy file to enforce its intended meta-policy. If a client is instructed to load a policy file other than the master
>   policy file,  the client must still check the master policy file to
>   ensure that the meta-policy defined by the master policy file permits the use of 
>   the originally requested policy file.
>
> Without a master policy file, it is left to the client to
>   enforce the default behavior. Instead of relying entirely on master
>   policy files for meta-policies, clients may also decide to check for a
>   `X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies` header in documents to specify a
>   meta-policy. In addition to the values acceptable in
>   permitted-cross-domain-policies, this header may also use a value of
>   none-this-response to indicate that the current document should not be
>   used as a policy file despite other headers or its content. Non-master policy files can only grant access to data within their own
>   directory or subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want to use the crossdomain.xml for a Flash client?
fact is, by default a flash client always tries to find that file in the root. as the specs state, everything else must be set in the client. I'm not a flash coder - you should tag this question with "flash" or whatever else the client is coded in.

Comment: I'm not a Flash coder either. This came to me when I was implementing the http://HTML5Boilerplate.com on a site where I only had access to a sub directory.

Comment: then it's easy: no API with proprietary clients = no need for crossdomain.xml. If you have an API for JavaScript clients on a different (sub-)domain you should instead send this header: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" (though the * can be replaced with a specific IP or domain)

Comment: Thanks. I don't need it—I'm just trying to understand it LOL. How you "send the header"—is that in JavaScript?

Comment: no, you do that with your server-config (apache, iis,...) or with server-side-scripting such as PHP (`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *')`)