# Flex simple corssdomain access

Tags: apache-flex

I am running trying to access form my local server a remote server.

> Error #2044: SecurityErrorEvent  : text=Error #2048: security sandbox : http://mydomain1.com/debaton/debaton.swf cannot access data from http://mydomain2.com/~debaton/services/gateway.php.

So I put crossdomain on 
http://mydomain2.com/~debaton/crossdomain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" />

</cross-domain-policy>
```

and put

```
 params.allowscriptaccess = "always";
```

in my HTML.

But still has this error!
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, crossdomain.xml needs to be at the root of the domain.  According to Adobe's KB - [Cross-domain policy for Flash movies](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html):

> Cross-domain policy files, named crossdomain.xml, are placed at the root level of a server.

Comment: +1 good catch; although I think that is not universal.  There are ways to put a crossdomain in subdirectories. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766688/how-to-add-crossdomain-xml-in-sub-directory

Answer (score 1):

Flash player will load the `crossdomain.xml` file from the root of the web server by default. If you want to load it from a subfolder you need to load it explicitly with:

```
import flash.system.Security;

Security.loadPolicyFile('http://mydomain2.com/~debaton/crossdomain.xml');
```

There is some more information on the [live docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Security.html#loadPolicyFile%28%29).